# Polyglot error: input contains invalid UTF-8 around byte 333789 (of 361147)

Tags: python, pandas, function, exception, polyglot

I am using Polyglot to detect English texts, I apply a function on a pandas dataframe but I get error. Here is my code:

```
def is_english(self, txt):
    # try:
    wrap = self.detector(txt)
    languages = wrap.languages  # The first language will be the most confident language, check if it's English and with more than 98% confidence!
    top_lan = languages[0]
    return top_lan.name == 'English' and top_lan.confidence >= 98

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df[df.input_text.apply(is_english)]
```

Error is:

```
pycld2.error: input contains invalid UTF-8 around byte 1383 (of 22731)
```

How can I surround that problem?
Thanks!

Comment: what's the input file content?

Comment: It contain very large text with some language (English, Korean, Russian, Arabic...), symbols, emojis, and so on

Comment: of course you don't post the whole thing but create a [mcve]. Just shorten the input file to a small example